# What is \363\353\377\377\377\177?

Tags: c, gdb

```
(gdb) p (char*)0x7fffffffe9c8
$16 = 0x7fffffffe9c8 "\363\353\377\377\377\177"
```

It doesn't look like ascii nor multibyte,what's that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) character escapes. They are usually used to insert bytes into a string that don't have a meaning as text or need to have a certain binary value. `\377` for instance is the hexadecimal value `ff` or decimal `255` which would be this `ÿ` in ASCII but most likely has a very different meaning in this context.

Comment: Because you told gdb to interpret it as `char*` which usually references text.

Comment: I guess this is because gdb *thought* that it might be more useful to show the actual binary byte values than to try to present it as letters which are off the usually recognized characters.

Comment: @cpuer: At least 2 reasons. (1) it's not valid UTF-8, and (2) GDB is probably too backwards to accept UTF-8 (or whatever the locale's multibyte encoding is) when printing strings, and instead just treats high bytes as "binary junk".

Comment: @R..,in the octal format,each `\xxx` represents exactly `1` byte,right?

Comment: Yes it's exactly one byte. More precisely, the octal number may consist of 1 to 3 octal digits after the \ and always denotes a single byte. I.e. `\0` is octal for the byte value `0` and `\11` is the tab char (byte value `9` or `\t`).

Answer (score 6):

It's not text. It looks like the address you're examining contains another pointer to something on the stack. Try it as `(char **)0x7fffffffe9c8`, or some other double pointer type.

**Edit:** To elaborate, OP is examining non-text data in a debugger and asking the encoding. The correct answer is simply that it's not text. It's an integer 0x7fffffffebf3 and it's almost certainly a pointer to a string (since it's not aligned and points somewhere on the stack), meaning that the original pointer was probably of type `char **` not `char *`.

Comment: Why the downvote? OP is examining non-text data in a debugger and asking the encoding. The correct answer is simply that it's not text. It's an integer `0x7fffffffebf3` and it's almost certainly a pointer to a string (since it's not aligned and points somewhere on the stack), meaning that the original pointer was probably of type `char **` not `char *`.

Comment: My apologies for the downvote - I misunderstood your answer. Reading over the explanation in your comment, the answer does make sense. Unfortunately I can't undo the downvote unless you edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The part that you asked can be the shell code to that address.

Answer (score 0):

try p/x

This should print value in hexa decimal format

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO. Thanks for providing an answer, but unfortunately it doesn't actually address what the question is about - clarifying the format of the example. Make sure to read up on [how to provide good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) so that your answers in the future can be more helpful (and get upvoted!).