# what is special character ‘\0’ in java strings and what's its significance and need?

Tags: java, string, ascii

I have searched but I found mixed answers. One site says string is terminated with a special character ‘\0’.

What is the purpose of the `\0` special character, and is the source correct?

[Source 1](https://www.quora.com/Do-strings-in-Java-also-terminate-with-a-0-character-like-strings-in-C)

[Source 2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strings-in-java/)

Comment: I think what the second link is saying is wrong.

Comment: Strings in Java are not nul-terminated: it has no special meaning.

Comment: The OP is asking about the use of the special character `\0`, not if strings are null terminated. This is not a duplicate of the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414873/does-java-define-string-as-null-terminated

Comment: The NUL character (which can be represented by `\0`) has no special meaning in Java Strings. As the linked duplicate states, it isn't used to terminate strings. As other control characters without specific meaning in java Strings (e.g. `\5` ENQ or `\6` ACK) it can be used in strings but will not appear when printed. It is up to you to give them a specific meaning (e.g. code an ascii-based protocol which sends ENQ for requests and expect an ACQ in return, or whatever you'd want)

Comment: Those links are good examples of why you should not trust anything other than the official documentation.  And highly up-voted Stack Overflow answers of course.

Comment: It's just text data; No intrinsic meaning to typical text functions. It might find usage in text formats for storage or interop outside of Java.

Answer (score 0):

The `\0` special character is part of a set of special characters used for octal values ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)). If you try `foo\377bar` it gives you `fooÿbar`. The `\0` in this case converts to `0o0` in octal, when this is converted to ASCII , reads as no string at all. If you have `foo\377bar`, the `\377` is converted from Octal to ASCII and is read as `fooÿbar`. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209560/what-is-363-353-377-377-377-177).

This suggests in Java `\0` is not used to null terminate a string, and further research shows Java doesn't use anything to null terminate strings, as the length of the string is enough to tell it that it has reached the end of the string.

This can be proven by running the following:

```java
String test = "foo\0bar";
char[] list = test.toCharArray();
for (char ch : list) System.out.println(ch);
System.out.println(test);
```

[image]

> EDIT: Java actually uses Unicode. This does not change the effect described above however, and `\0nn` can even be used to declare variable names, because of regular expressions in the lexical analysis stage of the compiler. [This](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=130880&seqNum=11) source goes through special characters, and explains how they can be used in Java. `\0` is the same as `\0n` where n is also 0, and is used as a null character. Kind of equivalent to Epsilon in RE, which is used to represent a string that is null.

Comment: `\0` isn't printed because it's a control character, but that doesn't mean it's disregarded by the compiler. You can create a `"foo\0bar"` String, and even though it will be printed as `foobar` it still contains 7 characters. You could then split that string over `\0` and end up with the two Strings `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Updated answer @Aaron

Comment: Yeah, still not a great answer IMO, not that it matters since the question has a duplicate, but if you care for feedback : 1) OP doesn't ask what's `\0`, but whether Java internally use that character to terminate strings 2) you shouldn't base your explanation of what `\0` is on the `Pattern` javadoc since the syntax it explains only is relevant for regular expressions, not for generic strings. I've tried and failed to find a relevant documentation though...

Comment: Well I mean, OP asks what `\0` is in the title actually. But the question's body clearly asks whether the strings themselves are NUL-terminated, and the two linked articles differ on that point

Comment: @Aaron OP states one site suggested it was used as null termination, but it appears they were looking for a clarification as to whether the source was correct, and if not what `\0` is actually used for.

Comment: I've deleted my answer since it's already covered by the duplicate which answers the first part of the question as you divided it and added a comment that hopefully covers the rest (in addition to this answer which explains the octal-indexing of `\xxx` raw characters sequences)

Comment: Java doesn't use ASCII. See [Character class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html).

Comment: @TomBlodget yes you are correct. It appears on further research that `\0` is used in Java as octal values, but is still classed as the "Traditional ASCII range". I found a good source explaining this, and have edited my answer accordingly

Comment: The existence of ASCII is not relevant to Java. [Octal character escapes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) cover U+0000 to U+00FF.